# Realm database open file

Tags: swift, realm, realm-database

I am working on my mobile app and with that I have been using Realm Database to store the user data. Further I have made a application for mac that is supposed to be able to open a realm file and display the user data from the file (Yes I know I can use Realm Studio for this, but I want to be able to develop my own application to add some features that my client needs). Does anyone know how I can open a realmfile on an mac app and make the realm code to use data from that file to fill out my tableview?

Thanks!

EDIT: Sorry for my unclear question. What I want is a way for realm database to get use data from a different file than the "default.realm" file. I have tried to see trough the documentation on realm.io but I could not figure it out, hope this cleared things up!

Comment: Welcome to SO. The question is quite unclear - opening a Realm file is pretty thoroughly covered in the Swift [Getting Started Guide](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/) which includes opening the file as well as reading the data. Do you have some code you're stuck on? If so, please include it in question with details of the issue. In the meantime, please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Based on an edit to the question, I believe the question is how to access a Realm file other than default.realm.

Here's one option; suppose you want to call your realm file todo.realm.

```
func setRealmFile() {
    var config = Realm.Configuration()

    // Using the default directory, append todo.realm
    config.fileURL = config.fileURL!.deletingLastPathComponent().appendingPathComponent("todo.realm")

    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
}
```

Comment: Ok, so if I want to use a realm file stored in the downloads folder I just use that path instead of the default directory? eg. config.fileURL = "than the path"?

Comment: @VegardJacobsen The code provided in my question assumes you want to use a realm file located in the same folder as the default.realm file. You can really point the URL anywhere you have access to. Keeping in mind that Sandboxing limits those options but to answer your question, yes.